# Como obter o url a partir do DevTools do Chrome

Tags: javascript, mvc

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function AbreModalEnvioRelatorioDiligencia(id, idProcesso) {
    debugger
    $("#myModal").load("..\..\_ComunicaDiligencia?idProcesso=" + idProcesso + "&idInformacao=" + id, //+ id,
        function () {
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
}
```

Existe alguma forma de saber qual o url que resulta dentro do .load()?

Comment: Talvez salvá-la em uma variável e no devtools pegar o valor dela?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss era o que estava a pensar, mas como é que poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Tenta abrir o modal, clica com o botão da direita nele, e manda "Exibir código fonte" http://prntscr.com/ongkcr vai abrir uma nova aba no Chrome com a URL do source http://prntscr.com/ongkvy é um procedimento manual, mas as vezes te ajuda de alguma forma a pegar o URL do modal gerado...

Comment: Nice, vou experimentar, não sabia que podia conseguir assim o url! Obrigado pela ajuda @hugocsl :)

Answer (score 3):

Vamos abstrair seu problema para um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável, sem dependências externas.

```js
console.log(`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/${Math.floor(Math.random()*1e6)}`)
```

Basicamente será exibido uma URL aleatória do Stack Overflow em Português, sem validá-la se existe ou não.

O objetivo é, através do `debugger`, verificar o valor que será passado como parâmetro para a função, então basta você salvar este valor em uma variável antes de utilizar o `debugger` e posteriormente acessá-la via Console.

```js
const url = `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/${Math.floor(Math.random()*1e6)}`
debugger
console.log(url)
```

Veja como ficaria no navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para o seu caso, seria algo como

```js
function AbreModalEnvioRelatorioDiligencia(id, idProcesso) {
  const url = "..\..\_ComunicaDiligencia?idProcesso=" + idProcesso + "&idInformacao=" + id;
  debugger;
  $("#myModal").load(url, function () {
    $("#myModal").modal();
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice, é uma boa cena! Mas tendo $("#MyModal").load("../../{accao}/{parametros}"), como é que conseguiria obter o url inteiro?

Comment: @Araújo Coloquei como ficaria para o seu caso... é exatamente a mesma lógica que apresentei anteriormente.

Comment: Nice, vou experimentar para ver se funciona, obrigado pela ajuda :)